# Scrolling nav bar disappears under other sections

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

**EDIT**: I did figure it out. 'overflow:hidden' inside the #main for the media query was making the nav disappear.

I have a scroll navigation at the top of my page, but when I scroll down the page, the nav bar goes under the next section, and no longer shows. It didn't always do this, only when I added my mobile and tablet media queries. If I remove the media query style sheet the navigation bar works just fine.

HTML

```
<section id="main">
<nav>   
    <a href="#about">About</a> 
    <a href="#motorcycles">Motorcycles</a> 
    <a href="#coffee">Coffee</a> 
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a> 
</nav>
<h1>Kickstart Cafe</h1> <h2>Coffee shop for the motorcycle enthusiast</h2>
```

CSS from the media queries

```
    small phone screen
nav {
    display:none;
}
#main {
    /*background-image: url('../img/beans.jpg');    */
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    h1 {
        font-size:3.25em;
        position:relative;
        padding-top:35%;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size:1.17em;
    }

}

desktop
@import 'styles';
#main {
    h2 {
        font-size:2.75em;
    }
}
nav {
    z-index:9999 !important;
}
```

CSS from the main stylesheet

```
#main {
margin:0;
padding:0 0 15% 0;
width:100%;
height:auto;
-moz-box-shadow: inset  0 -20px 10px -15px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0 -20px 10px -15px #000;
box-shadow:   inset  0 -20px 10px -15px #000;
nav {
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    a {
        color:#fff;
        font-size:2em;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin: 0 15px;
    }
}
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    top:0;
    a {
        color:#fff !important;

    }
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('nav').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    $('nav').addClass('fixed');
     } else {
        $('nav').css("top", "20px");
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
     }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps a brief jsFiddle could help us solve your problem. Have you tried z-index?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. Just use `z-index` CSS property.

```
z-index: 100
```

Add it to your `.fixed` selector

Comment: I have 'z-index: 9999' on the nav element and 'z-index:1' on all the others. Still does it.

Comment: That didn't work, but I did figure it out. 'overflow:hidden' inside the #main for the media query was making the nav disappear.